# SQLServer copy stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want a way to take a copy of my stored procedures into stored procedures with names like sp_oldprocedureName_yyyymmddhhmiss, programmatically, like:
(The following code is my "intension" code)

```
declare @DateExtension char(14)  
select @DateExtension = substring(CONVERT(varchar(30), getdate(), 120), 1,4) + substring(CONVERT(varchar(30), getdate(), 120), 6, 2)+ substring(CONVERT(varchar(30), getdate(), 120), 9, 2)+ substring(CONVERT(varchar(30), getdate(), 120), 12, 2)+ substring(CONVERT(varchar(30), getdate(), 120), 15, 2)+ substring(CONVERT(varchar(30), getdate(), 120), 18, 2)  

declare @OldName, @NewName varchar(255)  
set @OldName = 'sp_OldProcedureName'  
set @NewName = @OldName + '_' + @DateExtension  
sp_copy(@OldName, @NewName)  --This sp_copy does not exist, but I'm looking for an equivalent.
```

So, is there a procedure like the above "sp_copy"?

Comment: As an alternative to creating a new stored procedure, how about storing the text of the procedure in a tablename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_copy
    (@OldName VARCHAR(255),
    @NewName VARCHAR(255))
    AS BEGIN

BEGIN TRY
DECLARE @definition NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @definition = m.definition
   FROM sys.procedures p
   JOIN sys.sql_modules m ON p.OBJECT_ID = m.OBJECT_ID
   WHERE name LIKE @OldName;
IF @definition IS NULL
BEGIN
    PRINT 'There is no stored procedure with name: ''' + @OldName + '''';
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @definition = REPLACE(@definition, @OldName,@NewName);
    SET @definition = REPLACE(@definition, '''','''''');
    SET @sql = 'EXEC(''' + @definition + ''')';
    EXEC(@sql);
    PRINT 'Stored procedure duplicated successfully.';
END;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'There was an issue copying the stored procedure.';
END CATCH;

END;
GO
```

Then execute the code like this:

```
DECLARE @OldName VARCHAR(255)  , @NewName VARCHAR(255);  
DECLARE @DateExtension CHAR(14);  
SELECT @DateExtension = SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 120), 1,4) + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 120), 6, 2)+ SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 120), 9, 2)+ SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 120), 12, 2)+ SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 120), 15, 2)+ SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 120), 18, 2);  
SET @OldName = 'sp_OldProcedureName';  
SET @NewName = @OldName + '_' + @DateExtension;  
EXEC dbo.sp_copy @OldName, @NewName;
```

Answer (score 0):

OK - try the following. The procedure should work as you have specified. It will get the procs definition from sql_modules and execute it with the new name. Some debugging might be required.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spCopy @OLDNAME NVARCHAR(255), @NEWNAME NVARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @SQL = REPLACE(definition,@OLDNAME,@NEWNAME) 
    FROM sys.sql_modules 
    WHERE object_ID(@OLDNAME) = object_id

    EXEC @SQL
END
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution had some errors when I executed spCopy. But the solution made below by Flavia Obreja did the job!